# Como obter resultado de modelagem

Tags: mysql, modelagem

Possuo uma modelagem e estou tentando obter uma informação referente a ela, mas não estou conseguindo, preciso mostrar as tarefas do usuário separada por `Tipo de Atividade`, o usuário está na tabela `WFPessoaTarefa` campo `login`, vejam a imagem da modelagem:

[image: Modelagem]

```
DADOS DAS TABELAS RELACIONADAS
```

```
WFPessoaTarefa
IdTarefa    Login   LoginProxEtapa
1   9615    7580
2   7580    3015
3   3015    5461
4   5461    

WFTarefa
IdTarefa   IdEtapa  Ordem   Nome                  Descricao                        LinkDocumento                    DataInicio          DataTermino             EnviaEmail  Status
1          1        1       Preencher formulário  Preencher formulário             http://intranet.cocari.local/    2015-03-27 16:34:00 2015-03-31 16:34:00     1           1
2          2        2       Aprovar contratação   Aprovar contratação              http://intranet.cocari.local/    2015-03-27 16:34:00 2015-03-31 16:34:00     1           1
3          3        3       Aprovar contratação   Aprovar contratação              http://intranet.cocari.local/    2015-03-15 16:34:00 2015-03-29 16:34:00     1           1
4          4        4       Terminar processo     Terminar processo de contratação http://intranet.cocari.local/    2015-03-19 16:34:00 2015-03-10 16:34:00     1           2

WFEtapa
IdEtapa IdAtividade Ordem   Nome                DuracaoMaxima   EnviaEmail  Status
1       1           1       Proponente          48              0           1
2       1           2       Gerente             48              1   
3       1           3       Gerente Regional    48              1   
4       1           4       RH                  48              1   

WFAtividade
IdAtividade     Nome                        NumEtapas   Observacao                          IdTipoAtividade DataCriacao
1               Documento de contratação    4           Nenhuma observação para o momento.  2               2015-03-24 17:03:35
3               Documento de Avaliação      4           Nenhuma                             2               2015-03-27 16:27:00

WFTipoAtividade
IdTipoAtividade Nome
1               RH
2               Financeiro
```

[image: A query]

[image: Resultado esperado]

O que fiz foi isso:

```
SELECT 
  WFTipoAtividade.IdTipoAtividade,
  WFTipoAtividade.Nome AS TipoAtividade,
  WFPessoaTarefa.Login,
  WFEtapa.Nome,
  WFAtividade.Nome AS NomeAtividade,
  WFTarefa.Ordem,
  WFTarefa.DataInicio,
  WFTarefa.DataTermino,
  WFTarefa.`Status`
FROM
  WFTarefa
  INNER JOIN WFEtapa ON (WFTarefa.IdEtapa = WFEtapa.IdEtapa)
  INNER JOIN WFAtividade ON (WFEtapa.IdAtividade = WFAtividade.IdAtividade)
  INNER JOIN WFTipoAtividade ON (WFAtividade.IdTipoAtividade = WFTipoAtividade.IdTipoAtividade)
  INNER JOIN WFPessoaTarefa ON (WFTarefa.IdTarefa = WFPessoaTarefa.IdTarefa)
WHERE
  WFPessoaTarefa.Login = 9615
GROUP BY
  WFTipoAtividade.IdTipoAtividade,
  WFTipoAtividade.Nome,
  WFPessoaTarefa.Login,
  WFEtapa.Nome,
  WFAtividade.Nome,
  WFTarefa.Ordem,
  WFTarefa.DataInicio,
  WFTarefa.DataTermino,
  WFTarefa.`Status`
```

Quando executo o comando falha, isto é, não mostra o resultado, não sei onde estou errando.

Comment: Acho que dá pra adivinhar quais dados você tem na base e, destes dados, adivinhar qual resultado você espera. Mas seria mais produtivo você editar sua pergunta mostrando alguns dados de exemplo e explicando qual seria o resultado esperado.

Comment: Olá @Caffé, você tem toda razão, acabei de editar a pergunta, mas tambérm não sei se fui muito claro.

Comment: O ideal é mostrar alguns registros de cada uma das tabelas e depois mostrar como ficaria o resultado da consulta (como é o resultado esperado). Se você fizer uma pergunta completa sobre SQL uma resposta boa aparece aqui em minutos.

Comment: Não consigo ver nada errado. Talvez o problema esteja em outro lugar e não nesta query com estes registros. Experimente completar este exemplo aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdb4d/3/0, terminando de criar as tabelas com os demais campos e fazendo o insert dos demais registros. Se a query não funcionar aí também, clique em "link" (na parte de baixo da página) e cole a url gerada aqui para podermos avaliar.